# Apache HTTPD VirtualHost issues on port 443

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I'm trying to setup Apache HTTPD to work with Tomcat. Right now I have tomcat up and running and it is working fine (can access the web application by specifying the :8080 in the url). What I want to do is have Apache HTTPD redirect port 80 traffic to 443, have SSL become established, then have it reverse proxy traffic to Tomcat. The port 80 traffic redirect works using the REDIRECT directive (redirecting to https:// www. myregistereddomain.com). For some reason the virtual host directive is not resolving for the 443 traffic. I get an "Invalid method in request \x16\x03\x01" followed by "File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/501.shtml" in the apache error_log.

Link pertaining to issue: http://www.noah.org/wiki/Apache2_Invalid_method_in_request_%5Cx16%5Cx03%5Cx01

I have tried change the virtual host to **_*default*_**:443 and *:443, but it still throws the same errors. There are no other VirtualHost directives in the httpd.conf file so i'm not sure how it is not resolving to that virtual host on 443. It was initially "www.mydomain.com:443" and then i tried it by "IP:443", but still same errors. Anyone happen to have any idea what is wrong with the setup or any pointers on how to proceed to troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just using nginx. Was much easier to setup and get functioning as a reverse proxy.

Comment: Does nginx support the AJP protocol?